# ServerScriptService.Script:36: attempt to index number with 'CoinsAmount' (Roblox Studio)

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

So I am making data store for a simulator type game on roblox studio using luau and got this error which i cant crack.

Heres the code

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local CoinsStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("CoinsStore")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local stats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    stats.Name = "Stats"

    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local Coins = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    Coins.Name = "Coins"

    local Rebirths = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    Rebirths.Name = "Rebirths"

    local StomachMaxSpace = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    StomachMaxSpace.Name = "StomachMaxSpace"

    local Stomach = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    Stomach.Name = "Stomach"
    
    local UID = player.UserId
    
    --Load Data
    
    local data
    
    
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        
         data = CoinsStore:GetAsync(UID)
    end)
    
    if success then
        Coins.Value = data.CoinsAmount
        StomachMaxSpace.Value = data.StomachCapacity
        Stomach.Value = data.Stomach
    end
    
        
    
end)   

--save data

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local UID = player.UserId
    
    local data = {
        CoinsAmount = player.leaderstats.Coins.Value,
        StomachCapacity = player.Stats.StomachMaxSpace.Value,
        Stomach = player.Stats.Stomach.Value
    }   
    
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        CoinsStore:SetAsync(UID, data)
    end)
    
    if success then
        print("All Data Saved")
    end
    
    
    
end)
```

Please Help me solve the error because I need to get this game out

Error: ServerScriptService.Script:36: attempt to index number with 'CoinsAmount'

Answer (score 2):

I believe `CoinsStore:GetAsync(UID)` is returning a number, if this function is returning an error code, then you might want to check the return value of the function as well before continuing.

Comment: The error is not appearing on that line unfortunately. The error appears at the code Coins.Value = data.CoinsAmount

Comment: I understand, but the pcall does not ensure that the `CoinsStore:GetAsync(UID)` actually returns an object that has the `.CoinsAmount` member.

The error occurs at line 36 because I believe the `data` variable is not what you're expecting. You could print the return value right after assigning `data` to check.

Comment: @ben, the error is telling you that `data` is a number, not a table. So when you try to get any property out of `data`, like `data.CoinsAmount`, your code is like, "hey man, this is a number. I can't do that.". Perhaps when you were testing, you saved a number just to see if it would work. Now, instead of returning your nicely formatted table of values, it is still returning that old number the you were using for testing. Try commenting out the `CoinsStore:GetAsync(UID)` logic for one run, then turn it back on and see if the issue persists.